# Improving my broad question asking for advice that was also answered

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban

Regarding this question:
[Laravel: How to request data from database and dynamically update html select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083877/laravel-how-to-request-data-from-database-and-dynamically-update-html-select-el)

How can I improve this? I have stated my situation, what I plan to do and then if that is a good approach.

Looking back, I can see the question itself is bad, but I am trying to overturn a *question ban* so I cannot simply delete the question.

Comment: Asking what you *should* do or is there a better way is problematic. What is required is generally to actually attempt it and if you have issues THEN post **that** problem.

Comment: The question is way too broad. And to make matters worse it was answered. So changing the question so it’s a reasonable focused one would invalidate the answer. (Nothing would be lost by losing that answer, but that’s the problem with bad questions; they can attract that kind of response).

Comment: I understand your points and I agree. Is there anything I can salvage now, I guess not?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I can't see anything to salvage. I guess you could just leave it like that and next time try asking a better question. Or you could contribute in other ways such as editing, flagging, etc to override a question ban.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot ask anymore questions. Thank you for your input though, I will look at other questions I have asked to see if I can improve those.

Comment: Try improving this one to start off: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948818/laravel-yayrabox-datatables-how-to-handle-the-js-and-css-includes